# Forms - Input and return from button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make an input box where pressing the button causes the text to  change.

My code isn't working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script>
    function validate() {
         var inputObject = document.getElementById("name");
         var paraObject = document.getElementById("response");
         if ((inputObject.value.trim() == "") || (inputObject.value == null)) {
               alert("Invalid input!");
        }
        else { 
            paraObject.innerHTML = inputObject.value;
        }

    function blue(inputObject) {
        inputobject.style.border = "2px solid blue";
        }

    function required(inputObject) {
        if (inputObject.value.trim() == "") {
            inputObject.style.border = "2px solid red";
        }
        else {
            inputObject.style.border = "2px solid green";
        } }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
     Name:
     <br/>
     <input id="name" type="text" name="nameinput"onBlur="required(this)" onFocus="blue(this)"/>
     <button class="button" onClick="validate()">Validate Name Input</button>
     <br/>
     <p id="response">TEST</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: [Your validate function has no closing `}`](https://jsfiddle.net/apmvztsx/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing bracket } for the validate function.

Comment: I added the closing bracket and it's still not working.

Answer (score -1):

Add the script tag before the end of the body tag. Also add your scripts inside the onload event handler or $.ready if you are using jQuery

Comment: andy's fix seems to be working. check his [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/apmvztsx/1/)